# jQuery Mobile changePage() not working in Windows 8 Phone emulator

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have developed an application using Phonegap, jquery jquery-1.6.4 and jquery mobile-1.0.1. Application is working fine on IOS, Android and BlackBerry 10. Now I am trying to port my app for windows 8 phone but `$.mobile.changePage("#pageid");` is not working.

My HTML code is:

```html
<div data-role="page" id="emergency_Numbers" class="custom-background-image-college"> 
 <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" >
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-role="none" class="custom-button"  onclick="goBack()" >Back</a>
   <h1>Emergency</h1>
 </div>
 <div data-role="content" style="padding:5px;">                
   <ul id="ul_emergency_Numbers" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>                
 </div>
</div>
```

And I am calling from java script :

```js
function displayEmergencyPage() {
  var EmregencyNo = "";   
  EmregencyNo += "<li class='ui-btn ui-bar-f' data-role='list-divider' style='font-size:16px;'>Phone Numbers</li>";
  $.each(UIEmergencyObject, function(key, val) {          
    if(val.enabled == true) {
      teleNo = val.number;         
      EmregencyNo += "<li data-theme='d'><a href='tel:"+teleNo+"' ><label class='modifiedH3text' >"+val.name+"</label><p class='modifiedH4text'>"+val.number+"</p></a></li>";          
    }           
  });
  $("#ul_emergency_Numbers").html(EmregencyNo);  
  $.mobile.changePage("#emergency_Numbers");
}
```

I think there will be some different way to load page in windows 8.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution for this: I changed jquery version to jquery-1.8.2 and jquery mobile version to jquery.mobile-1.3.0 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

$.mobile.changePage as I can recall wont work for jquery 1.6.4,try upgrading jquery and jquery mobile and see if that makes any difference.Thanks